# Response ok in interceptor, but empty in onSuccess() method

Tags: android, retrofit

I am intercepting the response of a Request, using Retrofit, this way:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        client.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {

            @Override
            public com.squareup.okhttp.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                com.squareup.okhttp.Response respuesta2 = chain.proceed(chain.request());
                //respuesta=respuesta2.body().string();
                return respuesta2;
            }
        });
```

"respuesta" is a class variable, a String. As you see, it is commented.

Later, I am doing this:

```
Call<JSONObject> peticion=interfaz.login(imei, user, encriptedPass);
        peticion.enqueue(new Callback<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<JSONObject> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

                if(response.isSuccess()){
                    final AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                    builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.welcome));
                    builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.loginok));
                    builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.accept), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            loginDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    builder.create().show();
                    Log.i("David", "La respuesta: "+response.body().toString());

                }else{
                    try {
                        Log.i("David", "Error en la respuesta del login: " + response.errorBody().string());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    final AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                    builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.error));
                    builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.loginerror));
                    builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.accept), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            loginDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    builder.create().show();
                }
```

This way, it enters in the onSuccess method, but the response.body() arrives empty.

IF I uncomment the line above (//respuesta=respuesta2.body().string();) in the Interceptor, I have the JSON formed perfectly in the global variable respuesta, type String. But the execution goes to onFailure. I could manage the JSON there, as it is stored in a class variable, but it don't look as the proper way to do it.

Why does my response in onSuccess() comes empty, but I have it in the interceptor? How to get my response in onSuccess(), as it should be?

EDIT

By request, this is how I am setting Retrofit up:

```
Retrofit builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();

        final MyInterface interfaz = builder.create(MyInterface.class);
```

And I am calling the url using this method, in the interface:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST ("login")
Call<JSONObject> login(@Header("x-imei") String imei, @Field ("usuario")String usuario, @Field("password") String password);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New answer:**

Since you are using a `GsonConverterFactory` you should not declare `JSONObject` as the return type, but instead create classes that match your JSON structure and have Gson transform the JSON string directly to that classes.

There are a lot of tutorials on the web and questions here on StackOverflow regarding the details but feel free to ask, if you need any more help.

**Update:**

I just did a quick test and I *think* you should be able to declare `JsonObject` (that's `com.google.gson.JsonObject`, not `org.json.JSONObject`) as the return type. That way you would be able to navigate through the object using the key strings from your JSON structure.

**Old answer, based on misunterstanding the question:**

```
Response response = chain.proceed(request);

ResponseBody responseBody = response.body();
String responseBodyString = response.body().string();

// now we have extracted the response body but in the process have "consumed"
// the original response - it can be read only once. So, to return an intact
// response, we need to create a new one:

Response newResponse = response.newBuilder().body(ResponseBody.create(responseBody.contentType(), responseBodyString.getBytes())).build();

return newResponse;
```

Comment: But the line in which I am extracting the body from the response is commented, so I don't need to create a new one. My problem is that I have the JSON perfectly formed in the body of the response in the interceptor, but in the onSuccess() method I have it empty...

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, I misread your question - I thought it worked as long as you didn't uncomment that line. Can you show me how you set up your Retrofit?

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem is that the answer from the server is very, very complex, and there are lots of fields that are not used. So, instead of creating a bean from the fields of the answer, I was trying to simply get the JSONObject, and parse it by myself. Gonna try removing the converting line...